# PHP: fileperms() values and convert these

Tags: php, permissions, decimal, chmod, octal

Here is something i dont understand:

A file has the permission 0644 which if i use php´s fileperms() functions returns 16804 as integer if i make a var_dump(). What/where is the relation between the two and how can i convert a, lets say 0755, into whatever fileperms() would return for 0755.

THX

set*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

16804 is the decimal notation for the [octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) 40644. Check [2nd example of the PHP manual](http://php.net/fileperms) for the meaning of these values.

`40644` extracted:

- `4` - the file is a directory
- `0` - padding to get the first `4` on the 5th position
- `6` - read-writable for the owner
- `4` - readable only for the group
- `4` - readable only for the world.

PHP recognizes numbers with a leading zero as an octal number. If you need to convert a string containing `0755` or `755` to a decimal number, use [`octdec()`](http://php.net/octdec). The reverse function (decimal to octal) is [`decoct()`](http://php.net/decoct).

If you need to change the file permissions of a file, use [`chmod()`](http://php.net/chmod). For that to work, you need to be the owner of the file, otherwise you get a *Permission denied* error.

Comment: excellent ... i get it. the first index of the octal value is a little bit confusing. if 4 = directory what is a file then? i didnt find anything while searching the web.

Comment: According to the PHP example, a regular file is `0x8000` (octal: 0100000)